# Manipulate parameter passed in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I tried to dynamically create tasks through a range of dates. But I could not figure out how to execute things before the task is created

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "owner",
    "pool": "pool",
    "retries": 0,
    "start_date": datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 8),
}

dag = DAG(
    "airflow-ingestion",
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule_interval='5 8 * * *'
)

def driver(dag, **context):
    ...


logging.info(f"start the loop") // not executed
start_date_str = "{{ dag_run.conf.get('start_date', 'a') }}"
if start_date_str == "a": // not executed, the value is still a in the task
    start_date_str = "outside loop string" // not executed
logging.info(f"date {start_date_str} is not provided") // not executed
for x in range(1, 3):
    with dag:
        execution_date = "{{ ds }}"

        start_date_str = "{{ dag_run.conf.get('start_date', 'a') }}"
        if start_date_str == "a": // not executed
            start_date_str = "new string" // not executed
        logging.info(f"date {start_date_str} is not provided") // not executed
        ingest_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"ingest-{x}",
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=driver,
            op_kwargs={
                "dag": dag,
                "ingestion_file": "ingestion.py",
                "execution_date": execution_date,
                "start_date_str": start_date_str,
            },
            dag=dag,
        )
        ingest_task
```

The logging and the if check did not get executed. How should I check the parameters I passed before creating the task?